# How to get the full path of the parent directory / upper directory of the the current directory in command line

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

as shown below, I have a batch file named 'Current Path.bat' being stored in 'C:\A\B\'.

```
C:\A\B\Current Path.bat
```

What I want to do is to output the full path of the parent directory / upper directory of the the current directory (i.e. where the batch file is being stored / executed).

The expected result in this case should be:

```
C:\A\
```

Currently I have figured out a work-around for this, but it is not the perfect one. I am wondering if there is a better solution for this.

My work-around for the moment:

```
@echo off 
set current_path=%cd%
echo Current Path: %current_path% 
cd ..
set upper_path= %cd%
echo Upper Path: %upper_path%
```

The result is as below:

```
C:\>cd a
C:\A>cd b
C:\A\B>"Current Path.bat"
Current Path: C:\A\B
Upper Path:  C:\A
```

[The result of my work-around](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vEa2t.png)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with your approach; to avoid changing the current directory you can do, for example,

```
pushd ..
set upper_path=%CD%
popd
```

If you want to avoid changing directories even for an instant you can use a `for`:

```
for %%x in ("%CD%") do set upper_path=%%~dpx
```

Which of the two is more readable is your choice.

Comment: First of all, thanks for your help. The first approach advised by you works good, for the second one, it need to be modified a little bit before it can work correctly (seems like there should be two % before the ~dpx before it can work, otherwise, we will get the following error message: The syntax of this command is incorrect).

Seems like the correct one should be:

for %%x in ("%CD%") do set upper_path=%%~dpx

Comment: @JackChung: You are right, obviously. Edited the answer.